# R - Collapsing observations and creating new columns

Tags: r

In my dataframe there are multiple rows for a single observation (each referenced by `ref`). I would like to collapse the rows and create new columns for the `keyword` column. The outcome would include as many `keyowrd` colums as the number of rows for an observation (e.g. `keyword_1`, `keyword_2`, etc). Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot.

This is my MWE

```
df1 <- structure(list(rif = c("text10", "text10", "text10", "text11", "text11"), 
                      date = c("20180329", "20180329", "20180329", "20180329", "20180329"), 
                      keyword = c("Lucca", "Piacenza", "Milano", "Cascina", "Padova")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Maybe you want something like `unstack(df1[c(3,1)])` or `aggregate(keyword ~., df1, list)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% group_by(rif,date) %>% mutate(n = row_number()) %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = c(rif,date), values_from = keyword, names_from = n, names_prefix = 'keyword')
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   rif, date [2]
  rif    date     keyword1 keyword2 keyword3
  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 text10 20180329 Lucca    Piacenza Milano  
2 text11 20180329 Cascina  Padova   NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works perfectly; in my larger datsets do I just add all the other variables in `id_cols`?

Comment: @Edoardo, it's for uniquely identifying rows. If it works for your larger dataset, then go ahead.