# R - Collapsing observations and creating new columns based on multiple columns

Tags: r

In my dataframe there are multiple rows for a single observation (each referenced by ref). I would like to collapse the rows and create new columns for the keyword and the reg_birth columns.

```
df1 <- structure(list(rif = c("text10", "text10", "text10", "text11", "text11"), 
                      date = c("20180329", "20180329", "20180329", "20180329", "20180329"), 
                      keyword = c("Lucca", "Piacenza", "Milano", "Cascina", "Padova"), 
                      reg_birth = c("Tuscany", "Emilia", "Lombardy", "Veneto", "Veneto")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

If I just want to create the columns for the 'keyword' column I used this code, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970506/r-collapsing-observations-and-creating-new-columns).

```
df1 %>% group_by(rif,date) %>% 
mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
pivot_wider(id_cols = c(rif,date), values_from = keyword, names_from = n, names_prefix = 'keyword')
```

However, I don't know how to do the same for an additional column (reg_birth in this case).

This is my expected output

```
     rif keyword reg.birth keyword2 reg_birth2 keyword3 reg_birth3
1 text10   Lucca   Tuscany Piacenza     Emilia   Milano   Lombardy
2 text11 Cascina    Veneto   Padova     Veneto     <NA>       <NA>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I just included it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try with `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(id = data.table::rowid(rif, date)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = c(keyword, reg_birth))

#  rif    date     keyword_1 keyword_2 keyword_3 reg_birth_1 reg_birth_2 reg_birth_3
#  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
#1 text10 20180329 Lucca     Piacenza  Milano    Tuscany     Emilia      Lombardy   
#2 text11 20180329 Cascina   Padova    NA        Veneto      Veneto      NA
```

Comment: Great, thank you!